# Ctypes throws "WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application", but it's not a 32/64-bit issue

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, ctypes

I have a problem loading a Windows DLL in Ctypes, which throws the error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

In my case, it's a 32-bit DLL built with VS2012 on Windows 7 64-bit, and on my development machine I can load it fine. I checked that it's 32-bit, using `dumpbin /headers`:

```
FILE HEADER VALUES
         14C machine (x86)
```

The problem occurs when I try to load the same DLL via Ctypes on a production VM, which is also Windows 7 64-bit. What I'm doing is:

```
from ctypes import *
self.dll = CDLL(dllabspath)
```

I get:

```
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\WinPython-32bit-2.7.10.1\.....\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

From the other questions I've already tried several things.

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374710/windowserror-error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-in-python), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849077/error-loading-dll-in-python-not-a-valid-win32-application), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538671/python-call-to-external-program-results-in-error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-a) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621932/python-ctypes-load-library) question suggests that my environment has to be the same, i.e. 32-bit Python, 32-bit DLL. This is the case on my development system and the VM I'm testing on. On both, I'm using WinPython 32-bit, latest version. It works on the dev machine, it fails on the VM.
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27196098/python-embedding-with-ipython-windowserror-error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32), it's related to g++ and a dependency on old Visual Studio runtimes. I compiled everything with VS2012 so I don't think this is applicable here. There is a delayed-loaded dependency on a third party library that needs `MSVCR80.dll`, but it's delayed-loaded and never called.
- I've also installed the Visual C++ 32-bit Runtime on the target machine.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163832/python-simple-ctypes-dll-load-yields-error) suggests that the DLL needs to export a C interface, which it does.
- I know that the file path / file name to the DLL is correct, as before, there were issues with missing DLL dependencies, where I got a Windows popup. These are gone now.

The error is very generic, rather cryptic. Since it works on the dev machine in the same Python env, I'm assuming it has to do with some dependencies that only a Visual Studio installation can give me?

How can I troubleshoot this properly?

Comment: The message sometimes means that you got the filename wrong, for example specified a directory name instead of a full path to the DLL.

Comment: Run under a debugger such as cdb or windbg. Call `windll.kernel32.DebugBreak()` just before calling `CDLL(dllabspath)`. Set a breakpoint on `kernelbase!LoadLibraryExW` and resume the thread via `g`. When it breaks back into the debugger enter `pt` to execute up to the function return. Then enter `!teb` to check the `LastStatusValue` for the thread. This NT status value may be of more help.

Comment: @cdarke: The filename is 100% correct. Before, using the same code, I got popup errors for missing dependent DLLs.

Comment: If you prefer to keep the system as clean as possible, try the following: `windll.kernelbase.LoadLibraryExW(c_wchar_p(dllabspath), None, 0); status = windll.ntdll.RtlGetLastNtStatus()`.

Comment: Otherwise it requires installing the debugging tools from the SDK. Symbols can be downloaded on demand from Microsoft's symbol server by setting the environment variable `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH=symsrv*symsrv.dll*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`, which caches symbols in `C:\Symbols`.

Comment: @eryksun This is what I got when simply running everything, attaching to the process from WinDbg: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=jJaQKRN0 — and when I break on `LoadLibraryExW`, this is what I get when I do the thing with the breakpoint and `!teb`, as you suggested: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Akqrdiwm

Comment: There are several status codes that produce Win32 error `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT` (193). In your case it's `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT` (0xC000007B). Possibly in the production VM one of the dependent DLLs that it tries to load is 64-bit. At the breakpoint enter `du poi(@esp+4)` to print the first argument, which is the unicode path of the DLL it's attempting to load.  Also check the stack trace via `kc`.

Comment: @eryksun It worked. I found a dependency on a 64-Bit WinPCAP DLL. Going through everything with DependencyWalker, it looked the same on both machines, complaining about a 64-Bit dependency, but apparently on the fresh machine the DLL load path was different and it could never find the 32-Bit version. If you could put your tips with WinDbg into an answer, I'll gladly accept that. Thanks so much for your help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@eryksun commented:

> Run under a debugger such as `cdb` or `windbg`. Call `windll.kernel32.DebugBreak()` just before calling `CDLL(dllabspath)`. Set a breakpoint on `kernelbase!LoadLibraryExW` and resume the thread via `g`. When it breaks back into the debugger enter `pt` to execute up to the function return. Then enter `!teb` to check the `LastStatusValue` for the thread. This NT status value may be of more help.

Further:

> If you prefer to keep the system as clean as possible, try the following: `windll.kernelbase.LoadLibraryExW(c_wchar_p(dllabspath), None, 0); status = windll.ntdll.RtlGetLastNtStatus().`
>
> Otherwise it requires installing the debugging tools from the SDK. Symbols can be downloaded on demand from Microsoft's symbol server by setting the environment variable `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH=symsrv*symsrv.dll*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`, which caches symbols in `C:\Symbols`

When debugging, this may help:

> There are several status codes that produce Win32 error `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT` (193). In your case it's `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT` (`0xC000007B`). Possibly in the production VM one of the dependent DLLs that it tries to load is 64-bit. At the breakpoint enter `du poi(@esp+4)` to print the first argument, which is the unicode path of the DLL it's attempting to load. Also check the stack trace via `kc`.

Using this hint, I found a dependency on a 64-Bit WinPCAP DLL. Going through everything with *DependencyWalker*, it looked the same on both machines, complaining about a 64-Bit dependency, but apparently on the fresh machine, **the DLL load path was different** and it could never find the 32-Bit version.